# Run ElasticSearch. Bash: ./bin/elasticsearch: Permission denied

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, hortonworks-data-platform

I try to run Elasticsearch in Hortonworks Data Platform.
I got error "bash: ./bin/elasticsearch: Permission denied ".
Below you can see part of the script.
Could you help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
[root@sandbox-hdp elasticsearch-6.2.4]# sudo chown -R maria_dev elasticsearch-6.2.4
[root@sandbox-hdp elasticsearch-6.2.4]# su maria_dev
[maria_dev@sandbox-hdp elasticsearch-6.2.4]$ ./bin/elasticsearch
bash: ./bin/elasticsearch: Permission denied


[maria_dev@sandbox-hdp elasticsearch-6.2.4]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What file permissions does ./bin/elasticsearch has? Is it executable?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A log output alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It seems ./bin/elasticsearch doesn't have execute permission.

```
chown -R maria_dev elasticsearch-6.2.4
chmod -R 775 elasticsearch-6.2.4 
su - maria_dev
cd elasticsearch-6.2.4
./bin/elasticsearch-6.2.4
```